# Memory difference between arraycollection and dictionary in Flex

Tags: actionscript, dictionary, flex4, arraycollection

To optimize my application dictionary is a better option or arraycollection where both satisfy my needs. Please let me know. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Factually, arraycollection, arrays, dictionary, all act on the same internal data structure ,i.e a hashmap(or something similar).
Just that an arraycollection would have some pre-initialized memory slots unlike a dictionary.

Also, arraycollections are easier to deal with incase you need to iterate or do operations like shift, unshift etc.

So the question you should be asking is, what operations do i need to do on the data, and then decide which one you need to chose.

Comment: Hi @Neeraj, Dictionary is satisfying all needs which are required in my application, at the same time arraycollection too. Now,I want to know to optimize my application which is the better option.

Comment: @Kishore If your keys are always of the primitive type (i.e string, int, number etc) then you should go with an array collection not a dictionary.Incase your keys are other custom AS3 objects, then you should use a dictionary.